# Data size increases in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to import data from MySQL to HBase using sqoop. There are about 9 million records in the MySQL table, size being nearly 1.2GB. The replication factor of the hadoop cluster is three.
Here are the issues I am facing:

1. The data size after import to hbase is more than 20 GB!!! Ideally it
   should be close to, say 5GB (1.2G*3 + some overhead)
2. The HBase table has VERSIONS defined as 1. In case I import the same
   table again from MySQL, the file size in /hbase/
   increases (almost doubles). Although the row count in HBase tables
   remains same. This seems weird as I am inserting the same rows in
   HBase, hence the filesize should remain the same, similar to the row
   count value.

As far as my understanding goes, the file size in the second case shouldn't increase if I am importing the same rowset as max version maintained for each entry should be one only.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "some overhead" can get quite big in HBase as each value also stores the key, the family , the qualifier, the timestamp, the version and the value itself - you should strive to make the key, family and qualifier as short as possible.

Additionally you may want to use compression - [Snappy](http://hbase.apache.org/book/snappy.compression.html) is a good option (you can see [this post](http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/4605524309/lzo-vs-snappy-vs-lzf-vs-zlib-a-comparison-of) for a comparison between compressions)

regarding your second question. when you copy the table again you get another copy of each value. the other versions will be cleared after compaction. This is because HBase stores its data in Hadoop so once written the files are read-only. compaction creates new files which contains only the needed data and deletes unneeded data/files

Comment: It seems I asked my question too early, before HBase could actually compact the data and hdfs ignored the older version of the data. With time, the data finally settled to the expected size.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, according to this [blog](http://prafull-blog.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-calculate-record-size-of-hbase.html)

> So to calculate the record size: Fixed part needed by KeyValue format
> = Key Length + Value Length + Row Length + CF Length + Timestamp + Key Value = ( 4 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 1) = 20 Bytes
>
> Variable part needed by KeyValue format = Row + Column Family + Column
> Qualifier + Value
>
> Total bytes required = Fixed part + Variable part
>
> So for the above example let's calculate the record size: First Column
> = 20 + (4 + 4 + 10 + 3) = 41 Bytes Second Column = 20 + (4 + 4 + 9 + 3) = 40 Bytes Third Column = 20 + (4 + 4 + 8 + 6) = 42 Bytes
>
> Total Size for the row1 in above example = 123 Bytes
>
> To Store 1 billion such records the space required = 123 * 1 billion =
> ~ 123 GB

I would presume your calculations  are grossly incorrect, perhaps share your schema design with us and we can work out the math.

Comment: Got the maths now! Thanks for the explanation.